# iOS App XMPP chat server requirements

Tags: iphone, xmpp

We are planning to start a new iPhone chat app using XMPP. We didn't have any online VPS server now. We have a local server, on that openfire & XMPP is alredy installed. (We are using it for our local network chat on computers)

So my doubt is that can I start working on the iOS app with that local server now and later (after completing the app) is it possible to change to the online VPS server or need to start with online VPS server ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: of course you can use the local server for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible.

I started to develop the app on the local server by setting the xmppStrem hostName as the local server IP address.